# Should LaTeX counters always be modified globally?

Tags: counters, etoolbox, grouping

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/length-needs-backslash-but-counter-does-not-why/23281#23281) answer, egreg states that *"LaTeX counters should always be modified globally"*. However, the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package provides the `\defcounter` macro which will assign a value to a previously initialized counter *locally* (but may be prefixed with `\global`). I have been using this macro e.g. to change the value of the `secnumdepth` counter inside a group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\begingroup
\defcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\section{blubb}
\endgroup

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

So: Is egreg's statement about always globally modifying counters correct? If so, why? If not, is the usage of `\defcounter` in my MWE still bad practice?

Comment: It's discussed in the TeXbook (p. 301) or in TeX by Topic (p. 275).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As always with (La)TeX: If you know what you are doing you are allowed to do it!

Some local counter changes make perfectly sense, like in the example in the question. However I wouldn't call `secnumdepth` a real counter. After all it is never incremented. Here simply a counter register was used to store an integer because there is no other suitable type.
Real LaTeX counters for sectioning commands, lists or other stuff should normally be global, because they express a count which goes over the whole document and is not limited to local groups.
If you are so far that you need a local counter for your code you normally already know about `\newdimen` and can define a TeX counter instead of a LaTeX one.

A good example IMHO of a local redefinition of an otherwise global counter is shown in my answer to [Cross-referencing in multiple chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/cross-referencing-in-multiple-chapters/10410#10410). There I use `{\value{chapter}=<value>\relax\thechapter}` (which is kind of a dirty hack) so I can use the current `\thechapter` format but with a different chapter number as the current one.

PS: I usually code after the rule "Once global, always global!", except in special cases as explained above.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to egreg for pointing me to *[TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic)*. Here's the relevant quote (p. 275):

> Quantities that are assigned to inside a group must be restored after
>   the end of that group. The save stack is where the values to be
>   restored are kept; the size of the save stack limits the number of
>   values that can be restored.
>
> Alternating global and local assignments to a value will lead to ‘save
>   stack buildup’: for each local assignment following a global
>   assignment the previous value of the variable is saved. Thus an
>   alternation of such assignments will lead to an unnecessary
>   proliferation of items on the save stack.

Comment: Yes, indeed you should change a counter in a global and local way inside the same group. But adjusted a few values locally isn't an issue at all.

Answer (score 10):

Due to the nature of the TeX stack, you should use registers either locally or globally. Using primitives, that means something like

```
\newcount\mylocalcount
\newcount\myglobalcount
\begingroup
  \mylocalcount 10 %
  \global\myglobalcount 10 %
\endgroup
```

Thus if you want to use `\defcounter` for local assignments, you should not intermix it with `\setcounter` for the same counter.

In LaTeX3, we've formalised this by having `\l_...` and `\g_...` prefixes for variables.